# Dynamically setting RadioButton checked

Tags: android, xml, if-statement, radio-button, oncreate

I'm developing Android app and I have one problem. I have Radiobutton group:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/niezakonczoneRadio"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:onClick="niezakonczoneRadio"
android:text="Niezakończone" />

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/zakonczoneRadio"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:onClick="zakonczoneRadio"
android:text="Zakończone" />

</RadioGroup>
```

And I want to dynamically check one of it in if...else statement (in onCreate), like this:

```
if (status=="Zakończone"){
          RadioButton radioTak = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.zakonczoneRadio);

          radioTak.setChecked(true);
          status_radio="1";  
      } else {
          RadioButton radioNie = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.niezakonczoneRadio);
          radioNie.setChecked(true);
          status_radio="0";  
      };
```

Even if "status" variable is "Zakończone", the niezakonczoneRadio is checked. What is problem here? Generally there is checked one button all the time, no matters which value has the variable. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is obviously condition:

```
if (status == "Zakończone") { }
```

This always return **false**(you are comparing references not String values). Remember, whenever you want to compare Strings, you have to use `equals()` method.

So change it to:

```
if (status.equals("Zakończone")) { // or equalsIgnoreCase() }
```

Now it'll work. I strongly recommend you to read this:

- [How do I compare strings in
  Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

And remember one **golden rule**: Always you want to compare Strings `equals()` becomes your the closest friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
status.equals("Zakończone")
```

Use the string `equals` method